# What is an e+ value

Tags: raster, r

I am doing sensitivity analysis on my couple of raster files accumulatively. When I try to get min and max they give me values in 7.068148e+12.(picture is attached below for my raster values and ligand). I want min and max values, for my further analysis.  Can anybody explain it how we interpret this e+ values. What is max values for this one?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in exponential form. Consider zeros, e means total 12 number after ".", so exclude dot. So your max value is 7 068 148 000 000

Comment: To complete the answer it's a form of scientific notation to express number that are too large or too small to be conveniently written in decimal form. wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation